# gas_exhausted.operation when sending max balance

Tags: transactions, gas

**Environment:** Delphinet using `https://delphinet.smartpy.io`. I'm connecting to it through the RPC via the java/kotlin library [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

**Steps to reproduce:**

Trying to send my max XTZ balance to another account. The account is not delegated so it should be able to be empty.

- First dry-run the operation using `/run_operation` and `/forge` to get the fees, gas limit and storage limit. The simulation returns:

```
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
            "fee": "0",
            "counter": "780748",
            "gas_limit": "800000",
            "storage_limit": "60000",
            "amount": "692750",
            "destination": "tz1LnZxYuTUpf54cx8RWEX6EW9sZBoxGbqPQ",
            "metadata": {
                "balance_updates": [

                ],
                "operation_result": {
                    "status": "applied",
                    "balance_updates": [
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-692750"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1LnZxYuTUpf54cx8RWEX6EW9sZBoxGbqPQ",
                            "change": "692750"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-64250"
                        }
                    ],
                    "consumed_gas": "1427",
                    "consumed_milligas": "1427000",
                    "allocated_destination_contract": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- I send an operation that has:

  - `amount = max balance - (0.001591 ꜩ + 0.06425 ꜩ)` (baker fee + allocation fee)
  - `gas_limit: 1527`
  - `storage_limit: 257`

This returns an error: `proto.007-PsDELPH1.gas_exhausted.operation`

- If I add 1 mutez padding to that `amount` the operation runs with no problem (that mutez gets left as balance). [Example of this](https://delphi.tzkt.io/oneaAcUWfE4iD6cjFdgNYZoth5sskwRjXjz9MGUpty23Z3C91xb), where the balance was left as 1 mutez.

I tried this with several newly created accounts (all undelegated) and every time I tried to transfer all my funds found myself with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Raphael Cauderlier in [the gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/995) helped solve the issue:

"I have tried to reproduce this in sandbox (well, actually in mockup client); **I think your problem is that 100 extra gas units are not enough to empty an account, apparently this consumes 400 gas units**.
Here is what I did (`mockup_client` is an alias for `tezos-client --mode mockup --base-dir /tmp/mockup`):"

```
$ mockup_client create mockup
Base dir /tmp/mockup has state `base_dir_does_not_exist`.
Some commands (e.g., transfer) might not work correctly.
Created mockup client base dir in /tmp/mockup
Tezos address added: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
Tezos address added: tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN
Tezos address added: tz1faswCTDciRzE4oJ9jn2Vm2dvjeyA9fUzU
Tezos address added: tz1b7tUupMgCNw2cCLpKTkSD1NZzB5TkP2sv
Tezos address added: tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv
$ mockup_client gen keys alice
$ mockup_client transfer 100 from bootstrap1 to alice --burn-cap 1
[..]Consumed gas: 1427[..]
$ mockup_client transfer 99 from alice to bootstrap1 --fee 1
[..]Consumed gas: 1827[..]
$ mockup_client get balance for alice
0 ꜩ
```

I tried to run it with a `gas_limit = 1827` and [it worked](https://delphi.tzkt.io/tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn/operations/).